# How to resolve route53 issue? Routing to a cloudfront distribution that redirects http to https for a website hosted via s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I can verify the site hosted via s3 works fine (it's set to public access).
The cloudfront "link" works fine as well (it points to the s3 site) and is used to redirect http to https.

So that's why I think the issue is in route53.  I did some reading and I saw that the s3 bucket name must match, but the company has multiple domains registered and these all have worked

So this is the s3 bucket: `prod-subdomain` and the following works (I've setup some route53 A records that point to the cloudfront distribution)

- `subdomain.prod.site.com` (`prod.site.com` being the domain here)
- `subdomain.site.io` (`site.io` being the domain here)

However `subdomain.site.com` (`site.com`) doesn't seem to work.

I thought it had to do with the s3 bucket name, but the io route and `prod.site` route seem to prove otherwise.

I think it's gotta be something I'm not configuring correctly in route53 but I'm not quite sure how to move forward from here?

also the certificate being used is not the default one from cloudfront its `*.site.com`

Comment: The bucket name matching DNS thing only applies if you are doing S3 static website hosting *without* cloudfront. You really haven't explained what problem you are experiencing

Comment: oh my bad, im getting a time out issue (well the site seems to hang and then comes back with a timeout) so that's why i think the issue is in the r53 configuration